# FirebaseMLException on recognize Text in Image with ML Kit on Android

Tags: android, firebase-mlkit

I am using Google MLKit to recognize text from image. Unable to detect the text and falling in onFailure callback with exception as following
`com.google.firebase.ml.common.FirebaseMLException: batchAnnotateImages call failure`

I am using cloud version of Text recognize API not on device version.
Code is as following

```
private void readFromCloud(Bitmap bitmap){
    FirebaseVisionCloudDetectorOptions options =
            new FirebaseVisionCloudDetectorOptions.Builder()
                    .setModelType(FirebaseVisionCloudDetectorOptions.LATEST_MODEL)
                    .setMaxResults(15)
                    .build();
    FirebaseVisionImage image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(bitmap);
    FirebaseVisionCloudTextDetector detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance()
            .getVisionCloudTextDetector();
    Task<FirebaseVisionCloudText> result = detector.detectInImage(image)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FirebaseVisionCloudText>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(FirebaseVisionCloudText firebaseVisionCloudText) {
                    // Task completed successfully
                    // ...
                    readTextFromCloud(firebaseVisionCloudText);
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.e("FAILEd","Failed");
                    // Task failed with an exception
                    // ...
                }
            });
}
```

Stack Trace are as following:

```
06-12 14:28:41.547 13370-14113/com.example.gurithelpdesk_15.application1 E/ImageAnnotatorTask: batchAnnotateImages call failed with exception: 
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Write error: ssl=0x7a5b0ae800: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_write(Native Method)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLOutputStream.write(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:855)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$1.write(Okio.java:81)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$1.write(AsyncTimeout.java:155)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:176)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSink.write(RealBufferedSink.java:46)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$FixedLengthSink.write(HttpConnection.java:350)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:176)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSink$1.write(RealBufferedSink.java:198)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:126)
    at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.deflate(DeflaterOutputStream.java:254)
    at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.write(DeflaterOutputStream.java:212)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream.write(GZIPOutputStream.java:146)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:282)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:135)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:220)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzii.zzbu(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzii.zzbt(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzbh.writeString(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzax.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzax.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzax.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzax.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzax.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzax.zzd(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzat.writeTo(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzp.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzu.writeTo(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzap.zzaf(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzz.zzaa(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzf.zzj(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzhv.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzhu.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzgu.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzgp.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzgq.run(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Hi Manish, do you see this intermittent error from your production log? Or you could repro it locally? The Google Cloud Vision API endpoint has high availability and I think it might be due to your user's mobile network flakiness for this to happen. If you could repro, could you share more details your repro steps? Also, FYI https://pantheon.corp.google.com/apis/api/vision.googleapis.com/metrics to check your error ratio etc

Comment: @IsabellaChen The link you provided is not available to non Googlers…

Comment: Ah, thank you @LouisCAD. The correct url should be: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/vision.googleapis.com/metrics (can't edit above comment)

Comment: This is also a recurring issue in our current beta app. The same issue is also open in the [mlkit google code lab](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/mlkit-android/issues/7), as well as in this [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/jjMbnCdIeZ4). We are yet to resolve it either.